# Blender is rendering incompatible files

Tags: rendering

Have this problem when rendering stuff in Blender, when I try to render something it just creates this "fake" and incompatible *MP4* file but I can't open it or do anything other than <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> in Blender.

I have my output set on ffmpeg and mpeg-4.

Edit: *MP4* works on my system, but I've also tried other formats like rendering frame by frame in *PNG*, but it's still the same. I can not provide more information because that's just what happens, I do not know why.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information for it to be possible to determine the problem. Use another format for rendering. You could render to EXR format that way retaining most information in the render and then do adjustments and output the render to whatever video format you want. This way if some video format does not work on your system, you can try another without having to re-render.

Comment: Try setting your output settings to something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/nYcBn41), that might make it work for Windows.

Comment: You need to change the render file settings to inclode the mp3 audio codec

Answer (score 2):

[image: Default MP4 settings]

When you output MP4 in Blender, the default settings (above) produce a valid MP4 file but one that many media players don't recognize. The error code is a Microsoft code indicating that the player didn't recognize the format.

The most common problem is with the bottom highlighted entry "Audio Codec".  Switch that to "MP3" to have blender create MP4 files that are compatible with even more media players.  If that's not enough, change the 2nd highlighted entry "Container" to "MP4".  If that fails you may have encountered a bug in the libraries that Blender uses to encode output.